# Laravel 4: Separate superadmin auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to be able to have a separate login mechanism for admin users than our regular users. Authentication for general users is the default Laravel way. Using a users table and user model.

For our internal admin section (superadmin), I would prefer to use basic http authentication and not use the users table but no table at all or a new superadmins table containing only the users that can login to the superadmin.

What would be the best approach? Is there some way to hardcode a few superadmin login credentials or would a superadmins table be required? I was thinking of writing a custom auth driver but how would I load a custom auth config file only for the superadmin section? Preferably the custom auth driver would use a different cookie name as our superadmin users need to be able to login as users without constantly needing to re-login to the superadmin.

Comment: Maybe you can use `/admin` or `admin.` for the URL, throw this all in a route group for different superadmin controllers, and then use `.htaccess` to protect with a `.htpasswd` file?

Comment: Why dont you just have a column on your users table 'superuser'? Then just authenticate the normal way? Seems like alot of headache/work for not much gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Preferably the custom auth driver would use a different cookie name as our superadmin users need to be able to login as users without constantly needing to re-login to the superadmin.

This doesnt make sense. You cant be logged in as two different users at the same time, regardless how you set your cookies. You need some way to 'switch' between them.

Personally I think your making this too hard. Just have a column "superuser" in your users table. Then after you login the normal way - you can do something like

Filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth.superuser', function()
{
    if ( ! (Auth::user()->isSuperUser())) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Then in your routes file:

```
// Normal routes here
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'FrontController@showHomePage']);

Route::group(['before' => 'auth.superuser'], function ()
{
     // Superuser routes here
}
```

Edit - if you want to allow them to 'switch' between SuperUser and another userAlso - then do something like this:

```
function login()
{
      // login code here
      if Auth::user()->isSuperUser()
      {
          $cookie = Cookie::forever('superuser', 'really_long_secret_token');
          // Return with redirect AND cookie
      }
}
```

Then in your dashboard, or whereever - you can do:

```
@if (Cookie::get('superuser') === 'really_long_secret_token')
        Show superuser switch option here
@endif
```

That will work regardless if they are currently logged in as a superuser or not - because the cookie on the computer gives them the ability to switch to superuser whenever

Comment: Your answer seems very acceptable, seems like a good solution. But still a question. Why isn't it possible to have 2 different auth cookies? One of the main uses of our superadmin will be that superadmins will have a function to login as xxx using `Auth::loginUsingId()` which will set the auth cookie to that user if i'm not mistaken, overwriting the superadmin user. That was the main reason why I wanted to separate the 2 kind of users..

Comment: But how will Laravel know which one you "want" to be at any given point in time - you need to 'switch' between them. So having two cookies doesnt give you the ability to be two people at one time - you have to be one or the other.

Comment: Well that's indeed the problem, letting laravel load a different auth provider just for the superadmin controllers. That's why I was thinking of creating a custom auth provider, essentially the same as the normal one but using a superadmins table (or hardcoded array) and setting a different cookie.

Comment: If login as xxx wasn't a required feature, I would certainly go with your suggested solution. But I'm sure they're gonna complain if they continually have to re-login to the superadmin. The switch would only work when logged in as a superadmin. Once the login as a regular user, I can't show a switch.

Comment: Do they need to login as a different "regular" user - or just pretend to be a regular user? i.e. does the username "need" to be different?

Comment: Well they need to be able to access the regular user's admin

Comment: I've updated my answer - you can show a switch to the normal (super) user by setting a secret cookie

Comment: Thanks! What I'll do is place the cookie check in the `Auth::user()->isSuperUser()` function. This way superadmins will be able to access the superadmin pages regardless if they are currently logged in as a regular user.